# How do you display the number for each item in ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I've got this List which is assigned to itemscontrol in my xaml, I want to display the number for each item in the list:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string[] assignments = new string[] { "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/animals/48/Turtle.png", "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/animals/48/Butterfly.png", "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/animals/48/Dolphin.png", "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/animals/48/Elephant.png", "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/animals/48/Hippopotamus.png", "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/animals/48/Panda.png" };
        Random rnd = new Random();

        string[] randomingArray = assignments.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();

        string repeatNumber = "";

        List<string> animals = new List<string>(); 

        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (i == 9)
            {
                repeatNumber = randomingArray[i % randomingArray.Length];
                animals.Add(repeatNumber);
            }
            else if ((i % 9) == 0)
            {
                animals.Add(repeatNumber);
            }
            else
            {
                animals.Add(randomingArray[i % randomingArray.Length]);
            }
            ItemsControl1.ItemsSource = animals;
        }
    }
}
```

The code of xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ItemsControl1" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
                    <Image Source="{Binding}" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Basically, there should be boxes with picture in them numbered from 1 - 99

I have tried List.count method and other things that involve xaml into them, however i can't get it to work.

Comment: Create a ValueConverter that counts and show that value not matter what it's bound to might work. Or store it a struct with the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class with Number and Image source as properties and update your ItemTemplate. See below code.

```
<ListBox x:Name="ItemsControl1" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Source}" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>

                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string[] assignments = new string[] { "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/animals/48/Turtle.png", "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/animals/48/Butterfly.png", "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/animals/48/Dolphin.png", "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/animals/48/Elephant.png", "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/animals/48/Hippopotamus.png", "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/animals/48/Panda.png" };
        Random rnd = new Random();

        string[] randomingArray = assignments.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();

        string repeatNumber = "";

        List<ImageSource> animals = new List<ImageSource>();

        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (i == 9)
            {
                repeatNumber = randomingArray[i % randomingArray.Length];
                animals.Add(new ImageSource(){ Source = repeatNumber, Number=i });
            }
            else if ((i % 9) == 0)
            {
                animals.Add(new ImageSource() { Source = repeatNumber, Number = i });
            }
            else
            {
                animals.Add(new ImageSource() { Source = randomingArray[i % randomingArray.Length], Number = i });
            }
            ItemsControl1.ItemsSource = animals;
        }
    }
}

class ImageSource
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
}
```